what is a working way of using jest with pnpm and esm
My monorepo is trying to use pnpm, workspace protocol, ts-jest and esm and npx jest in the libraies/social-media cwd is giving the error message shown below.
See libraries/social-media/jest-config.mjs for various things tried.
I may have an insufficient understanding of the transformIgnorePatterns property in my configuration or if jest is a good choice. Must I build first then test the transpiled js?
Steps to Reproduce
See the reproduction repo on GitHub.
git clone https://github.com/GaryB432/pnpm-workspaces.git
cd ./pnpm-workspaces
git switch social-media-testing
cat ./libraries/social-media/jest.config.mjs
pnpm install
pnpm run --recursive build
pnpm run --recursive test
# observe the error message shown below

Error Message
D:\xxx\libraries\shared\dist\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from "./lib/message.js";
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

> 1 | import { message } from "@pnpm-workspace/shared";
    | ^
  2 |
  3 | export const exclaim = message.concat("!");
  4 |

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/.pnpm/jest-runtime@29.7.0/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/tweeter.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/tweeter.spec.ts:2:1)


Folder Structure
|   package.json
|   pnpm-lock.yaml
|   pnpm-workspace.yaml
|
+---apps
|   \---greeter
|       |   package.json
|       |   tsconfig.json
|       |
|       +---dist
|       |   \---app
|       |           main.d.ts
|       |           main.js
|       |
|       +---node_modules
|       |   +---.bin
|       |   |       ...
|       |   |
|       |   \---@pnpm-workspace
|       |       \---shared <-- symlink to .\libraries\shared
|       |
|       \---src
|           \---app
|                   main.ts
|
+---libraries
|   +---calculations
|   |   |   jest.config.mjs
|   |   |   package.json
|   |   |   tsconfig.json
|   |   |
|   |   +---dist
|   |   |   |   add.d.ts
|   |   |   |   add.js
|   |   |   |   multiply.d.ts
|   |   |   |   multiply.js
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   \---lib
|   |               add.ts
|   |               multiply.ts
|   |   |
|   |   +---node_modules
|   |   |   +---.bin
|   |   |   |       ...
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   \---@pnpm-workspace
|   |   |       \---shared <-- symlink to .\libraries\shared
|   |   |
|   |   \---src
|   |       |   index.ts
|   |       |
|   |       \---lib
|   |               add.spec.ts
|   |               add.ts
|   |               multiply.spec.ts
|   |               multiply.ts
|   |
|   +---shared
|   |   |   jest.config.mjs
|   |   |   package.json
|   |   |   tsconfig.json
|   |   |
|   |   +---dist
|   |   |   |   index.d.ts
|   |   |   |   index.js
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   \---lib
|   |   |           message.d.ts
|   |   |           message.js
|   |   |
|   |   +---node_modules
|   |   |   \---.bin
|   |   |           ...
|   |   |
|   |   \---src
|   |       |   index.ts
|   |       |
|   |       \---lib
|   |               message.spec.ts
|   |               message.ts
|   |
|   \---social-media
|       |   jest.config.mjs
|       |   package.json
|       |   tsconfig.json
|       |
|       +---dist
|       |   |   index.d.ts
|       |   |   index.js
|       |   |
|       |   \---lib
|       |           tweeter.d.ts
|       |           tweeter.js
|       |
|       +---node_modules
|       |   +---.bin
|       |   |       ...
|       |   |
|       |   \---@pnpm-workspace
|       |       \---shared <-- symlink to .\libraries\shared
|       |
|       \---src
|           |   index.ts
|           |
|           \---lib
|                   tweeter.spec.ts
|                   tweeter.ts
|
\---node_modules
    |   ...


package.json
{
  "name": "@pnpm-workspace/source",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "packageManager": "pnpm@9.12.3",
}


libraries/social-media/package.json
{
  "name": "@pnpm-workspace/social-media",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@pnpm-workspace/shared": "workspace:^",
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.4",
    "@tsconfig/strictest": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^22.8.0",
    "globals": "^15.11.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.2.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}

libraries/social-media/jest.config.mjs
Important I think
Please see the commented version in the reproduction repro for things I've tried.
import { createDefaultEsmPreset } from "ts-jest";

const defaultEsmPreset = createDefaultEsmPreset();

/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
const config = {
  ...defaultEsmPreset,
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: { "^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$": "$1" },
};

export default config;

libraries/social-media/src/lib/tweeter.ts
import { message } from "@pnpm-workspace/shared"; // <-- is this a problem?

export const exclaim = message.concat("!");

libraries/social-media/src/lib/tweeter.spec.ts
import { describe, expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { exclaim } from "./tweeter.js";

describe("Tweeter", () => {
  test("exclamation", () => {
    expect(exclaim).toEqual("hello world!");
  });
});

libraries/social-media/src/index.ts
export * from './lib/tweeter.js';

libraries/social-media/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": [
    "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
    "@tsconfig/strictest/tsconfig.json"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "dist"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}

Dead ends
Jest errors with solutions - DEV Community
typescript - JEST - SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' with uuid library - Stack Overflow
node.js - Jest Typescript with ES Module in node_modules error - Must use import to load ES Module: - Stack Overflow
Getting Started · Jest
kulshekhar/ts-jest: A Jest transformer with source map support that lets you use Jest to test projects written in TypeScript.
Should I just use vitest
